# Go strings.Replace(input, "\n", "", -1) did not recognized

Tags: go

I'm trying to process the strings inputted by users, and wrote following code.

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var input string
    fileScanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    fileScanner.Scan()
    input = fileScanner.Text()
    replaced := strings.Replace(input, "\n", "", -1)
    fmt.Println(replace)
}
```

But I found "\n" was not replaced to "". "\n" does not seems as a string.
I tried it "." or "," instead of "\n" and it works.
I just started learning Go and this question might be too fundamental, but I appreciate for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

"\" characters are processed as escape characters within a formated string and hence wont be replaced by `strings.Replace`

If you are really trying to replace the \n character itself, not the new line putting it inside a raw string literal should help. Refer the code below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var input string
    input = `\naaa`
    replaced := strings.Replace(input, `\n`, "", -1)
    fmt.Println(replaced)
}
```